# CLR/CLI linker fails with error LNK2022 - Custom attributes are not consistent

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, preprocessor, clr

**Environment:**
`Visual Studio 10, CLR/CLI Class Library` project, built with `Platform Toolset v100`, targeting framework version `v3.5`.

I am aware that this question was already asked here, but I did not find an answer that solved the problem for my case, so bringing this up again.

While building a `CLR/CLI Class Library (DLL)` project the linker is failing with the following errors:

```
MSVCMRT.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000f7).
MSVCMRT.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000fb).
MSVCMRT.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c000128).
MSVCMRT.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c00012c).
MSVCMRT.lib(puremsilcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000ee).
MSVCMRT.lib(puremsilcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000f1).
LINK : fatal error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors
```

Comment: Have you set the CLR flag properly? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/047d168c-e759-47a7-8e1d-bfbed12d35d0/error-lnk2022-metadata-operation-failed-custom-attributes-are-not-consistent

Comment: Yes: Set `/clr` in both places...

Comment: Duplication of class name due to including same file twice can also cause this warning. Check if you have not included a header in pch.h and then again in some other file that refers that pch

[microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2022?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Another thing I learned on the way is that **you cannot mix values** of `Platform Toolset` and `Target Framework Version`.

The possible combinations I found where:

**.NET 3.5 or less:**

- `Platform Toolset`: **v90**, which will use `Visual Studio 2008` runtime binaries,
- `TargetFrameworkVersion`: **v3.5** (or less),
- In the preprocessor you can have `_WIN32_WINNT` defined (e.g. `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500`)

**.NET 4.0 or higher:**

- `Platform Toolset`: **v100**, which will use `Visual Studio 2010` runtime binaries,
- `TargetFrameworkVersion`: **v4.0** (or higher),
- In the preprocessor you **must not** have the '_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500' defined

**How to define these values:**

1. `Platform Toolset` – find it under: Project settings | General,
2. `TargetFrameworkVersion` - Unload the project, right-click on the unloaded project and select 'Edit'. Once the '*.*proj' file is open, modify the following line: `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5<TargetFrameworkVersion/>`

Comment: I guess there is no other way then installing Visual Studio 2008 to get the Platform Toolset v90, isn't it?

Comment: Where to get Visual Studio 2008 runtime binaries? Googling didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

#### Remove the `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500` definition from the C/C++ Preprocessor

Apparently for some reason the above preprocessor definition did not agree with the linker, causing the linker errors. I assume this is some internal Microsoft bug (?), but not sure.
Anyway, after removing this preprocessor definition all built and linked correctly.

Hope this information is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I had some header files in some of the compilation units that set the Windows version:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
```

The problem was with the other compilation units (c++ files) that **didn't** set that variable, so the `error LNK2022` is complaining that the same struct is compiled in different ways in multiple compilation units (different cpp files).

So I can't just unset the `_WIN32_WINNT` definition, so my solution was quite the opposite of what was suggested before.

I just set it for the whole project, so all the compilation units compile the same way.
**project properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions**

```
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a C# dev but I had to wrap native C++ code and ended up with this same error.

Turns out I had to use `make_public` to expose the native type publicly to the C++/CLI assembly:

```cpp
#include "SomeHeader.h"
#pragma make_public(SomeNamespace::NativeClass)
```

As I understand this is usually used when the header file cannot be edited.