# Targeting .NET 3.5 in VS 2013

Tags: .net, visual-c++, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2013, backwards-compatibility

The task is simple: compile a C++ CLI assembly that targets .NET 3.5, in Visual Studio 2013.

As MSDN suggests, I changed the project file as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
  <ProjectGuid>{38B30DA5-524F-48E5-9F87-792FA9AE2E69}</ProjectGuid>
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  <Keyword>ManagedCProj</Keyword>
  <RootNamespace>chardet.net</RootNamespace>
  <ProjectName>chardet.net</ProjectName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It happily compiles but the targeting framework is 4.0:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18571546/656243